# Sorting and separating code in Node.js

Tags: node.js

How to sort text in node.js. I scrape webpage and get console log something like this:

> `22.777.000.1794219RCNvndsfdsgreg2 rnc 99 aiknx aha`

I cant scrape any specific parts of this, it all comes in one peace. I want to separate it and get specific parts of it.

Comment: `str.split` or regex

Answer (score 0):

It's an console log message. Check your code where it is printing like this. Apply breaks wherever required